# What's a good name for a façade class?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, naming-conventions, facade

A little background: We're building a library/framework for working with scientific models.  We have an interface `Model` which defines the operations that a model must implement, which is pretty minimal.  That is: the `Model` interface defines the contract of a model *from the point of view of a model implementor*.

The framework adds a bunch of other functionality around the model, but right now client code has to access that functionality by using a bunch of other classes, such as `ModelInfo`, `ModelHost`, `ModelInstance`, etc.

In our application that uses this framework, we don't want to actually have to deal with all this mechanism of running models, etc.  So we've decided to use the [façade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) to wrap up the framework functionality in an easy-to-use object.  (We've already applied this pattern to other parts of the framework, with good success.)

Here is the question: given that we already have an interface `Model`, **what would be a good name for the façade class?**  The `Model` interface is the contract between the framework and the *model implementation*, and the new class will define the contract between the framework and the *client application*.

Or, more generally: when we have an abstraction provided by a library or framework, **how can we name the "two sides" of the abstraction so as to clearly identify the "provider" and "consumer" interfaces to the abstraction**?

(If it matters, for this project we're using Java 6.)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I know this seems trite, but... have you considered using "`ModelFacade`" as the class name for the facade class?  I think with documentation that indicates that the interface was already named `Model`, it seems relatively straightforward, and makes it very clear which design pattern you're using.

Comment: Agreed -- and in fact that is the working name I'm using while developing the class right now.  But from the point of view of the client application, it feels inelegant to create and use "ModelFacade" objects all over the place.  Mainly, I wanted to ask the question to see if there were any other good alternatives.

Answer (score 3):

How about *Provider and *Consumer? I think you said it yourself in your question. Perhaps *Producer and *Consumer is a better match?

Comment: Yeah, I considered that.  But `FooProvider` seems to be to be a class that constructs or retrieves `Foo` objects, not a class that provides "foo" functionality.  Additionally, in our client application, we're already using Guice's `Provider<T>` interface all over the place, and so introducing a new, different, use of "provider" seems like a bad design.

Answer (score 2):

In discussions within our team, another option has been proposed: we can rename the existing `Model` interface to something else, and just call the new façade `Model`.  In fact, they can both be called `Model` right now, because they will live in separate packages.  (Although I'm not a fan of identically-named classes in different namespaces.)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like ModelInfo, ModelHost, and ModelInstance should all be members of Model.

See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/316840/is-it-bad-practice-to-name-a-class-with-a-facade-suffix for why you generally shouldn't name classes with the specific implementation used. Basically, some day you may want to use a different implementation of Model, which happens to not be a facade.

Answer (score 0):

PureMVC uses a singleton named `ApplicationFacade` and registers all the models with methods like `registerProxy` which are defined in `IFacade`